# Database table design for 'availability' within time ranges per day

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am working on a meeting scheduling web-app, where a person can share their availability for specific time ranges within the day.

E.g. A user is available 3 time-ranges within the day, from `09:10 to 10:00`, `13:00 to 14:00` and `16:30 to 17:15`.

This can go on for 6 days per week, from Monday to Saturday.

What I came up with:

```
Users:
- uuid
- sername

Days:
- pk
- name (eg. Monday)
- slug

Availability (mapping table):
- user_uuid
- day_id
- timerange

Schedule:
- pk
- schedule_id
- day_id
- user_id
- meeting_id
- time_from
- time_to
- status
```

But I have no clue how to query between time ranges and get all the users who are available at that time, If I search for a user who is available from `16:30 to 16:50` I am not really sure how to do that.

I'm using PostgreSQL

```
Availability:

user_uuid   |   day_id   |  timerange
-------------------------------------------
b1b14b30    |   3        |  '09:15 - 10:00'
a7f611ea    |   1        |  '13:05 - 14:05'
a7f611ea    |   1        |  '16:30 - 16:45'
```

```
Scheduled meeting (2 users having a meeting):

schedule_id   |   user_uuid   |   day_id   |  timerange
-------------------------------------------------------------
1             |   b1b14b30    |   3        |  '09:15 - 10:00'
2             |   a7f611ea    |   1        |  '09:15 - 10:00'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results -- as *text tables* in the question.

Comment: What is the second table ( which has **Scheduled meeting (2 users having a meeting):**)? Do you want to query for the time range `16:30 to 16:50`?

Comment: Yes I want to know If a user is available in that time range, so query the Availability table

Comment: Make life easier for yourself and use range types and function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html & https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html. Take the string value you have in timerange and split into two time fields. Then use the information in the links to do range math.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver wow thanks a lot, I'll probably go with that

Comment: If you do I would take a look at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING. This allows you to have a 'unique' constraint on user/day/time range combo if you use the btree_gist extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to first have a timerange table which is keeping the time ranges at the 5 minute interval, something like below. You should not keep time_range as textual field. Keep them in the `time` datatype.

**TimeMaster**

```
+----------------+------------+
| TimeIntervalId | Timevalue  |
+----------------+------------+
|              1 |    00:00   |
|              2 |    00:05   |
|              . | .          |
|              . | .          |
|            288 |  23:55     |
+----------------+------------+
```

Every interval representation should utilize this time master table. In this way, you can easily do all time calculations.

```
Users:
- uuid
- sername

Days:
- pk
- name (eg. Monday)
- slug

Availability (mapping table):
- AvailabilityId, PK
- user_uuid
- day_id
- Start_timeIntervalId
- End_timeIntervalId

Schedule:
- schedule_id, Pk
- day_id
- user_id
- meeting_id
- meetingstart_timeIntervalId
- meetingend_timeIntervalId
- status
```

Answer (score 1):

Using range types is certainly a good solution for your use case. However you can think of storing timestamps (range_start and range_end) in epoch format (mainly bigInt datatype). Methods to convert epoch to readable timestamp and vice versa are available with PostgreSQL.

Epoch values will keep the implementation, primarily around availability check, simple.

https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: I had designed a similar data model for a recurring event app couple of years back. Please take a look if it can be a help for you - https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/again-and-again-managing-recurring-events-in-a-data-model/

Answer (score 1):

The Availability table should be defined like this :

Availability (mapping table):

- user_uuid
- day_id
- timerange_start type `TIME with time zone`
- timerange_stop  type `TIME with time zone`

Then to find all users that are available that day is to run

```
select * from Availability where day_id = YOUR_DAY_ID and 
timerange_start < YOUR_TIME_START and 
timerange_stop > YOUR_TIME_STOP
```

I think one week is not enough , so you should save the full date. You need to mark that a person is assigned to a meeting , so either to delete the row from Availability or to add a status field. Good luck !